# React Native render function gives an error : Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying out a basic example to work on AsyncStorage on react native. When I try to run the application, it throws an error at the render function.

Here is my code-

```
var AsyncStorageExample = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            arr : [],
        }
    },

    stateSetting: function(arrval) {
        this.setState({
            arr : arrval,
    },

    render : function() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.arr.map(arr =>
          <Text key={arr.name}>
            &bull; {arr.name}
          </Text>
        )};
      </View>
    );
  },

});
```

Error is thrown at the **:** of render function `render : function(){`
**Unexpected token** is what I get on the red screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this

```
this.setState({
            arr : arrval,
```

should be

```
this.setState({
            arr : arrval,
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my issue. But, I am stuck at another issue now. It says - Invariant Violation: RawText ";" must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component. I am using <Text> component to wrap it. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I could rectify the <Text> one as well. Thanks for the response.